# Remote POSIX socket connection in plain C++ application

Tags: android-ndk

I am working on a Java Android app which packages a plain C++ application as an asset. During execution, the Android app extracts the C++ binary to its private filesystem subfolder, runs it as a background process using `java.lang.ProccessBuilder`, and then sets up sockets for bidirectional communication.

Socket connections work just fine, as long as the native process only wants to talk to its Java parent. The problem is when the native process tries to open a socket connection to a remote server, such as a website domain. In this case, calls to the POSIX function `int connect(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len)` fail with error code `ENETUNREACH` (no route to network).

I am aware that an Android app must have permission `android.permission.INTERNET` added to its Manifest before it can access Internet resources. I have done it to my Android app, but apparently this permission doesn't carry over to native subprocesses spawned from Java code.

I also figure I could rewrite the whole system so the C++ process would delegate such remote requests to its Java parent. But what I really wanted was to find a way to allow the background C++ application to access the Internet on its own.

That's because that C++ code is actually a port of a relatively complex Linux application, to which the "Android app" works as UI. I *could* extend this architecture so the native app would use the Android app as a proxy to the Internet, but I'd rather not have to; however so far I haven't found a way to do enable native apps direct access to the network stack, short of recompiling the kernel (which in my case is not an option, as this application must run in stock Android devices).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm, that really shouldn't happen - after all, this is how a lot of applications work and you're not doing anything extremely extravagant. Do check that your <uses-permission> is outside the <application> tag and that you can make connections from Java-land. Also, try listening on a port, can you forward that port over adb and does that work? 

This is most definitely something on your end though the possibilities are endless without narrowing it down first.

Comment: Apparently this problem was somehow connected to running the code in a custom Android build – moving to a stock image solved the problem.